# Filter tbl_sqlite column by string comparing with another column - dplyr

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

This maybe a novice question.How do I filter with matching string values with values from another column using dplyr when working with a database?
e.g. I want to do something like this.

```
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)
head(nycflights13)
```

Lets say I want to filter for rows with origin values contained in destination values, I tried

```
filter(flights_sqlite, origin %in% (unique(select(flights_sqlite,dest))))
```

However that operation is not allowed. I do not want to convert this to dataframe as the database that I am working with is large and will eat up any available ram.

Comment: What if you try `filter(flights_sqlite, origin %in% dest)`?

Comment: I take it you are married to `dplyr` for this? Using `RODBC` and actual SQL query strings would give you more flexibility.

Comment: @docendodiscimus - that query also fails since it is looking for a table named dest